# Read a csv file that is stored in Attachment Object

Tags: apex, attachment, csv, excel, emailfileattachment

I have an excel/csv as an attachment related to an EmailMessage. I want to read the csv, process the data and create certain records(of custom object) based on that data. I want to understand how I can read the attachment using apex?

What I am trying to do is, get the information from an attachment.

```
Attachment attachmentRecord = [Select Id,Body,ContentType from Attachment  WHERE ParentId =<my EmailMessageId>];
 
System.debug('a ' +attachmentRecord.Body);
System.debug('b '+attachmentRecord.Body.toString());
```

When I print the body, I get the output as :

> a Blob[13381]

if I convert it to string(2nd debug statement) I get an error saying :

> System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string

I want to understand what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs, I have included additional info in my question, hope it helps. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @AwaisAhamed file with which extension is actually this attachamnet? is it a plain text or it is an excel file with `.xlsx` format?

Comment: Its a csv file with .csv extension

Answer (score 1):

I was able to read a csv file from attachment record, using below apex code:

```
Attachment attachmentRecord = [Select Id,Body,ContentType from Attachment  WHERE ParentId = <Parent Record Id>];
String csvAsString;
String[] csvFileLines;
csvAsString = attachmentRecord.Body.toString();
csvFileLines = csvAsString.split('\n'); 
        
for(Integer i=1;i<csvFileLines.size();i++){
   string[] csvRecordData = csvFileLines[i].split(',');
   System.debug('csvFileLines '+i+' '+csvRecordData[0]);
   System.debug('csvFileLines '+i+' '+csvRecordData[1]);
   System.debug('csvFileLines '+i+' '+csvRecordData[2]);
   System.debug('csvFileLines '+i+' '+csvRecordData[3]);
 }
```